# MySQL JOIN take more than 10 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, join

in short, there are two tables, `activities_log` with 3.3M rows and `posts` with 20K rows.
When some query join them its take more than 15s !!! (╥﹏╥)

What I'm doing wrong? What I could do to optimize?

It is running in this server:

- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
- Digitalocean droplets / 4 GB Memory (4 GB Swap) / 60 GB Disk
- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-43-generic x86_64)

```sql
# QUERY:
select `posts`.`page_id` from `activities_log` left join `posts` on `posts`.`id` = `activities_log`.`post_id`;
3345753 rows in set (17.40 sec)

# EXPLAIN:
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+--------+---------------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table          | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key                          | key_len | ref                                | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+--------+---------------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | activities_log | NULL       | index  | NULL          | activities_log_post_id_index | 145     | NULL                               | 3203032 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | posts          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY                      | 144     | prod_api_v1.activities_log.post_id |       1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+--------+---------------+------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

select count(*) from `activities_log`;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  3345770 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.04 sec)

show index from activities_log;
+----------------+------------+------------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name                           | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------+------------+------------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| activities_log |          0 | PRIMARY                            |            1 | id            | A         |     2984883 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| activities_log |          1 | activities_log_page_id_index       |            1 | page_id       | A         |         343 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| activities_log |          1 | activities_log_activity_id_index   |            1 | activity_id   | A         |          15 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| activities_log |          1 | activities_log_post_id_index       |            1 | post_id       | A         |       43894 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| activities_log |          1 | activities_log_session_token_index |            1 | session_token | A         |        4431 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| activities_log |          1 | activities_log_user_id_index       |            1 | user_id       | A         |       17908 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------------+------------+------------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select count(*) from `posts`;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    19999 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

show index from posts;
+-------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name                 | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| posts |          0 | PRIMARY                  |            1 | id           | A         |       16647 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| posts |          1 | posts_page_id_index      |            1 | page_id      | A         |         324 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| posts |          1 | posts_kind_post_id_index |            1 | kind_post_id | A         |           8 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| posts |          1 | posts_posted_by_index    |            1 | posted_by    | A         |          31 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+--------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT:

This query is just a example. I don't really want the pages id. A real example could be: `select * from activities_log left join posts on posts.id = activities_log.post_id where activities_log.page_id = X or posts.page_id = X`

Comment: It can take a while to return such a large volume of data.

Comment: . . Can you explain what you want your query to do.  It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I really want know if has something that a can do to do this query faster or when join 3M rows always take so long.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  separated  indexes  for each column you should use composite redundant index  for

table

```
  activities_log    column  ( post_id, page_id)
```

with left position post_id (the column involved in join clause) and after the page_id  ..  this column is useful for avoid the access to table data and obtain all the data from  the index  table

You should take in mind that a query can use   just a single indexc for each table involved

Comment: well, I added a new index ('post_id', 'page_id') but result is the same. (16.52 sec)

Comment: yes, query uses `activities_log_post_id_page_id_index`

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out what you are trying to accomplish.  You have a `left join` and are returning rows from the *second* table so these could often be `NULL`.

My best guess -- despite your query -- is that you want the pages of all posts that have an activity.  If this is the case, then you can phrase the query as:

```
select p.page_id
from posts p
where exists (select 1
              from activities_log al
              where p.id = al.post_id
             );
```

At the very least, this will return a much smaller result set.

Comment: This query is just a example. I don't really want the pages id. A real example could be `select * from activities_log left join posts on posts.id = activities_log.post_id where activities_log.page_id = X or posts.page_id = X`

Comment: @BrunoCosta . . . You should ask a new question with a query that serves some use.